# Qt/QML performance degrading with other OpenGL application running at the same time

Tags: qt, opengl, qml

I am having a somewhat curious problem I am running into for the second time now writing an application in Qt/QML. I am working on Windows 10 with Qt 5.11.1.

When I run a QML window with a couple of graphical elements in it (mostly Rectangles, Text, Shapes, that sort of stuff), I notice that the update performance degrades and it starts to lag severely behind the data as soon as I start another application that uses OpenGL to render. As long as the QML app runs alone the performance is fine. The other OpenGL app always runs smoothly too, whether it is running alone or together with the QML window.

I am using QtQuick and I understand that it uses OpenGL, hence my connection to the other OpenGL app I run at the same time, but I may be wrong. Both applications however do not communicate with each other at all. The second app uses GPU resources quite intensely, but only to about 50%, while the QML resource usage seems negligible.

The other application apparently uses GLUT, it is a custom in-house app which I cannot share unfortunately. Since I work on a company laptop, updating display drivers or that kind of thing is not an option either, but I assume they are at the latest version.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on here, or what things to look for?

Comment: Hard to be sure. Read on QSurfaceFormat. Play with ```    auto f = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
    f.setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenVG);
    f.setVersion(2, 0);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(f);
``` also try QSurfaceFormat::setSwapBehavior. And if the system graphics is not powerful and OpenGL compatible enough then that makes all things even more unclear. I had a bad experience with Intel on CPU chip video. Now cannot remember in details but even the environment how to start matters. Read on QSG_RENDER_LOOP env.variable parameters.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderV! I will look into that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.